# Troubles with cross-compiling simple program for OpenWrt

Tags: c++, g++, cross-compiling, openwrt

I downloaded OpenWRT-SDK for my router architecture from official website.

> OpenWrt-SDK-15.05.1-ar71xx-generic_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2.Linux-x86_64

OpenWRT-SDK and OpenWRT on my router has same architecture and version. Computer OS is Debian 7.

---

My task: compile simple program on PC and run it on router.

For begining I exported STAGING_DIR enviroment variable:

> export STAGING_DIR="/sdk/ar71xx-generic/staging_dir"

"/sdk/ar71xx-generic/" - its path to OpenWRT-SDK directory.

And wrote simple program on C++

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For compile this for OpenWRT I used this command from terminal from my sources directory:

> $STAGING_DIR/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin/mips-openwrt-linux-g++ -o helloworld main.cpp

In output I got this error:

> mips-openwrt-linux-g++: error trying to exec '/sdk/ar71xx-generic/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin/../lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.8.3/../../../../mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/bin/as': execv: Exec format error

But if I compile my sources using standard g++ compiler - all works fine.

Comment: are you able to compile a c code?

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://trac.gateworks.com/wiki/OpenWrt/SDK#OpenWrtToolchainUsage and see if it gives you the clues you need.

Comment: I compile this program by adding STAGING_DIR to environment variables and call directly g++ compiler from command line.